# extract data from string and between characters in php

Tags: php

I want extract data from string

Example, i have this :

```
n97(nok)_100(ok)_n41(145)_23(ok)
```

I want get the 2 string beginning by "n" :
n97(nok) and n41(145)

And after for this 2 string i need get in variable 
97 => nok and 41 => 145

can you help me ?
Thanks you

Comment: What you did till now?

Comment: The idea of SO is we try and **help to fix** your code! **We do not write your code**

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: To ask an On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Hi Yes i try that  $Nbcontrole = substr_count($controle,'_')+1;
$i=0;
While($i<$Nbcontrole)
{
$defaut = explode("_", $controle);
$controleNOK = substr($defaut[$i], 0,1);

if($controleNOK == 'n') {
$defautn = substr($defaut[$i], 1, 9999999);

echo $defautn;

} else {
} 
$i++; 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex `/n(\d+)\((.+?)\)/` to find patern and array_combine to get result

```
$str = 'n97(nok)_100(ok)_n41(145)_23(ok)';
if(preg_match_all('/n(\d+)\((.+?)\)/', $str, $m)) {
   $res = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
}

print_r($res);
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/957364)